# want to retrieve values from database for xml tags in java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, xml, jdbc

hi i want to retrieve values from SQL database for xml tags using java coding
i hav written a code to connect database... i am able to query the database... created a .xml file using documentbuliderfactory and transformerfactory.Now output is like this

```
public class New

        void condb() {    /*written code to connect databse*/
            try {
                /*code for get xml tags*/
                                 stmt = connection.createStatement();
                String querystring = ("select CId from company");
                rs = stmt.executeQuery(querystring);
                System.out.println("\n" + "CId");
                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "    ");
                }
                Element child1 = doc.createElement("Company");
                child1.setAttributeNS(xlink, "xlink:type", "");                                         child1.setAttributeNS(xlink, "xlink:show", "  ");
                child.appendChild(child1);
               /*code for xml*/
                bw.flush();
                bw.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception in connecting to DB" + e.getMessage());
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
            New e = new New();
            e.condb();
        }
}
```

i want to get values for xlink:type=" " and xlink:show=""from database ... i tried declaring variable name and assigning queries to it,called that variable name in the " " field.. but it doesn't work... please can anybody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: You'll get much more help if you show your problem code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you need to store in xml the company list from your database.
Try this:

```
            while (rs.next())
            {
                Element child1 = doc.createElement("Company");
                child1.setAttributeNS(xlink, "xlink:type", rs.getString (1));
                child1.setAttributeNS(xlink, "xlink:show", "  ");
                child.appendChild(child1);   
            }
```

Though I don't quite understand your sql query

```
select CId from company
```

Is company a table or some other select query?

Comment: This solves half of my problem. i can acesss values for one attribute... but for second attribute this showing index out of range...

Comment: company is tabale name... and i given same name to taglist too

Comment: Correct your query to select all required attribute values from company table in a required order. rs.getXXX expects column index, but your query returns only one column.

Comment: i am not understanding above lines...... i have 2 columns CId And Cname. i put rs.getstring(1) and rs.getString(2). but its giving following error    Exception in connecting to DBThe index 2 is out of range.
The index 2 is out of range.

Comment: And i tried with one more while loop . then its giving following error          Exception in connecting to DBThe result set is closed.
The result set is closed.

Comment: You need to select one more column in your query: `select CId, Cname from company`.